# cds toolbox - Exception: Missing/incomplete configuration

Tags: python-3.x

cds toolbox - Exception: Missing/incomplete configuration

This is the code :

```py
import cdsapi

c = cdsapi.Client()

c.retrieve(
    'reanalysis-era5-single-levels',
    {
        'product_type': 'reanalysis',
        'variable': [
            '2m_temperature', 'cloud_base_height', 'total_precipitation',
        ],
        'year': [
            '1980', '1981', '1982',
            '1983', '1984', '1985',
            '1986', '1987', '1988',
            '1989', '1990', '1991',
            '1992', '1993', '1994',
            '1995', '1996', '1997',
            '1998', '1999',
        ],
        'month': '10',
        'day': '16',
        'time': '21:00',
        'format': 'netcdf',
    },
    'download.nc')
```

This is my output :
[image]

Comment: Dont post a link of your code, add your code here

Answer (score 0):

go to user directory `C:Users\username`

create a text file (like sample.txt) and change its name to `.cdsapirc` i.e you have to create a file with extension `.CDSAPIRC` (it should not be having any name, its just a file with extension like `.conda`)

open this file with any text editor like `Notepad++`

paste this in your `.cdsapirc` file

```
url: https://cds.climate.copernicus.eu/api/v2
key: xxxxx:xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
```

you will get your own UID and API key from your user information via this URL or simply click on your username on the upper right corner, it will direct you to the page

```
https://cds.climate.copernicus.eu/user/
```

so in the line change credentials as

```
key: UID:API-Key
```

**Your Python File should work Now**